# Horizontal Menu with columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have categories being called from the database and they are going past the bottom of the screen which is making users scroll down to see them all.

If you look at the image, that is what I am after.

I have looked at examples and I can get the effect if I manually add the links, but I want them to get called.

Here is the code for the links.

```
<div class="menu">
      <a class="toggleMenu" href="#"><img src="images/nav_icon.png" alt="" /></a>
        <ul class="nav" id="nav">
        <li><a href="/pages/about" class="scroll">About Us</a></li>
        @foreach($sections as $section)
        <li class="section">
            <a href="#" class="cat-toggle dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ $section->name }}</a>
            <ul class="categories dropdown-menu">
                @foreach($section->categories as $category)
                    <li><a href="{{ url('/category/'.$category->id.'/show') }}">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </li>
        @endforeach
            <li><a href="/pages/engineering-services" class="scroll">Engineering Services</a></li>
           <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">Contact Us</a></li>
           <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

This is done in laravel.

Here is an example of what I am after
[image]

css

```
.menu{
    float:right;
    padding-top: 1%;
}
.menu li{
    display:inline-block;
}
.menu li:first-child{
    margin-left:0;
}
.menu li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.menu li a:hover ,.menu li.active a{
    background:#000000;
    color:#4BCAFF;
}
#nav .current a {
    color:red;
}
.toggleMenu {
    display:  none;
    padding: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.nav:before,
.nav:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.nav:after {
    clear: both;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
```

Comment: Where is your CSS code etc.. ?

Comment: You need to include the css and js code, because this is a jquery effect that is triggered dynamically when the user clicks on your `what we do` button. Basically jquery or javascript will `.toggle()` a div (which before was hidden) so that you can see that navigation. The div will have a css class that style it. You have to find this class and edit it as you want to obtain your desired style. There is no need to edit the javascript/jquery code. You just edit the css class.

Comment: Updated all of the code.